# Handbrake preview video "Missing GStreamer plugin"

Tags: video, vlc, gstreamer, handbrake

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and chose to install non-free codecs upon installation. 
But apparently I'm still missing some codecs. 
When I want to preview a file in handbrake, I get these two errors:

[image]
[image]

When I want to play a video in Totem I get this error:

[image]

But it doesn't find anything in Ubuntu Software and the video does play. In VLC I don't get any errors.

Here is the list of installed `gstreamer` plugins.

```
dpkg -l | grep gstreamer
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64                 1.16.2-2                                   amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.16.2-4                                   amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64             3.0.27-1                                   amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-gl:amd64                      1.16.2-4                                   amd64        GStreamer plugins for GL
ii  gstreamer1.0-gtk3:amd64                    1.16.2-1ubuntu2                            amd64        GStreamer plugin for GTK+3
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                   1.16.2-2                                   amd64        ffmpeg plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-packagekit                    1.1.13-2ubuntu1                            amd64        GStreamer plugin to install codecs using PackageKit
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64            1.16.2-4                                   amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps             1.16.2-4                                   amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64            1.16.2-1ubuntu2                            amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64            1.16.2-2build1                             amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64              1.16.2-1ubuntu2                            amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                         1.16.2-2                                   amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-vaapi:amd64                   1.16.2-2                                   amd64        VA-API plugins for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                       1.16.2-4                                   amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64                 1.16.2-4                                   amd64        GStreamer GL libraries
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64        1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1                          amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64       1.16.2-4                                   amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64       1.16.2-1ubuntu2                            amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                    1.16.2-2                                   amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0:amd64                1.2.0-5                                    amd64        C++ bindings library for GStreamer with a Qt-style API - Qt 5 build
```

Comment: Did you installed Handbrake from official repository? What is the output of `apt-cache policy handbrake`?

Comment: I installed the snap version. When I try the normal package from john stibbins PPA I do not receive these errors. I still get the error regarding `DVD subpicture decoder` in totem tough.

Comment: Did you try to use Handbrake 1.3.1 from [*universe*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=handbrake&searchon=names)?